# About Python3 semantics

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting

So I was doing a problem that counts the minimum number of swaps required to sort a list of numbers 1, 2, 3, ..., n.

Now I was able to solve this problem but I had to do a very specific thing with the syntax to get it to work. Does anyone mind helping me understand why I had to do it this way.

My original code is:

```
def minimumSwaps(arr):
    c = 0
    
    for index in range(len(arr)):
        value = arr[index]
        if not index + 1 == value:
            #new_i = arr.index(index+1)
            print(str(index) + " -> " + str(new_i))
            arr[index], arr[arr.index(index+1)] = arr[arr.index(index+1)], arr[index]
            print(arr)
            c += 1
            
            
    print(arr)
    return c
```

The problems with what this code outputs is:

1. On the first iteration it does no actual swapping but it recognizes that things should be swapped, see output
2. On the last iteration it does no swapping but it recognizes there needs to be a swap
3. Therefore it ends up not swapping enough

Example:

Input: [4, 3, 1, 2]

Output:

```
0 -> 2

[4, 3, 1, 2]

1 -> 3

[4, 3, 1, 2]

2 -> 1

[4, 1, 3, 2]

3 -> 0

[2, 1, 3, 4]

[2, 1, 3, 4]
```

Now when I change my code to this:

```
def minimumSwaps(arr):
    c = 0
    
    for index in range(len(arr)):
        value = arr[index]
        if not index + 1 == value:
            new_i = arr.index(index+1)
            print(str(index) + " -> " + str(new_i))
            arr[index], arr[new_i] = arr[new_i], arr[index]
            print(arr)
            c += 1
            
            
    print(arr)
    return c
```

where all I did was store the "arr.index(index+1)" in a var and use that variable instead of the expression in my swapping code, it works perfectly.

Example:

Input: [4, 3, 1, 2]

Output:

```
0 -> 2

[1, 3, 4, 2]

1 -> 3

[1, 2, 4, 3]

2 -> 3

[1, 2, 3, 4]

[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I'm pretty stumped by this, please help.

**Edit 1**: It actually does not run perfectly, I get runtime errors I think exclusively on larger inputs, of course.

Comment: Original code references `new_i` but never assigns to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the order of operations in:

```
arr[index], arr[arr.index(index+1)] = arr[arr.index(index+1)], arr[index]
```

The order on the right side of the `=` is fine; all of that occurs before anything is modified, so you end up with a `tuple` of the expected values.

The problem is that the *left* side of the `=` is evaluated from left-to-right, *lazily* (each target is only evaluated at the moment that item is assigned) so the `arr.index(index+1)` call occurs *after* the assignment to `arr[index]`. The order of operations is (see bolded italicized part for the crux of the problem):

1. Right side `tuple` constructed (does a lot of stuff, but none of it dangerous)
2. `arr` loaded
3. `index` loaded
4. Index assignment performed, assigning the first element of the `tuple` from #1 to `arr[index]`. **`arr` has different values now!**
5. `arr` loaded again
6. `arr.index(index+1)` called on ***the `arr` already mutated by step 4!!!***
7. Index assignment performed, assigning the second element of the `tuple` from #1 to `arr[post_mutation_index]`

So when the assignment to `arr[index]` means that `arr.index(index+1)` returns a different  index, your code misbehaves. Caching it off beforehand fixes it, because it views the pre-mutation `arr` and uses it consistently.

To make things more clear, your code is equivalent to:

```
tmp = arr[index], arr[arr.index(index+1)]
arr[index] = tmp[0]
arr[arr.index(index+1)] = tmp[1]
```

(just without a named `tmp`). With that ordering, it's more clear that the `arr.index(index+1)` call comes after `arr` has already been mutated, allowing it to find (or not find) a value due to `arr[index]` being assigned a new value before searching for the index to use when assigning the other value.

You could also make the code work by ensuring the left-side `.index` call occurs before any other mutation, e.g.:

```
arr[arr.index(index+1)], arr[index]
```

but that's going to be fragile code (if a maintainer changes the order, or adds additional items to the line it's harder to make it right), and it's less efficient that caching it once up front anyway (you have to do two linear scans of `arr` for every swap, not just one).

That works because the ordering is now:

1. Right side `tuple` constructed (does a lot of stuff, but none of it dangerous)
2. `arr` loaded
3. `arr.index(index+1)` called on the *unmodified* `arr`, and never called again after any index assignments have occurred (GOOD!)
4. Index assignment performed, assigning the first element of the `tuple` from #1 to `arr[pre_mutation_index]`
5. `arr` loaded again
6. `index` loaded
7. Index assignment performed, assigning the second element of the `tuple` from #1 to `arr[index]`

Comment: Okay, so where does my runtime error come in. Even after I have cached the new index into a variable?

Comment: @Skips: That wasn't in your original question. Edit in a traceback for the exception you're seeing, and I might be able to help; without a [MCVE] (including inputs that trigger it, expected outputs and observed behavior) it's much harder to answer your question. It's also possibly a new question, since it's likely unrelated to the issue you had with intermingling `.index()` calls with multi-assignment.